# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in template_preprocess_update_report()

Tags: 8

In a Drupal 8 install, I visit `/admin/reports/updates`, and I receive the following error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   template_preprocess_update_report() (line 44 of
>   core/modules/update/update.report.inc).

From [this page](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2017-01-11/unable-to-check-update-status-for-drupal-core-or), I have tried to the run the SQL query:

```
delete * from 'prefix_key_value' where collection = 'update_fetch_task';
```

but I receive error:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '* from 'prefix_key_value' where collection =
>   'update_fetch_task'' at line 1

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this page](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2017-01-11/unable-to-check-update-status-for-drupal-core-or) I tried an SQL query to remove `* from 'prefix_key_value' where collection = 'update_fetch_task';` but that failed, so I deleted the `update_fetch_task` entry manually from the `prefix_key_value` table.

That resolved the error.

Answer (score 1):

`delete * from ...` is invalid SQL, you don't need the asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

From [the same page](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2017-01-11/unable-to-check-update-status-for-drupal-core-or#comment-12983262) referenced in the question, you need to have an update.settings.yml file, which can be set at ./admin/reports/updates/settings

Once you have this file, the update report screen at ./admin/reports/updates should work.